# In SilverStripe/GraphQL 4 how do I get the bulkLoader auto generated schemas to allow has_many and many_many updates?

Tags: graphql, schema, silverstripe

My GQL schema is generated via the bulk loader but it's create and update input objects don't have fields corresponding to has_many or many_many relationships, even though the read queries do.

Is there something I'm missing in the setup that gets the generated schemas to allow many_many relationships on things like createMyObjectInput? Or is there another way I'm meant to update these relationships?